# Right way to Run a Vue App with Phoenix application as proxy

Tags: heroku, vuejs2, elixir, phoenix-framework

Right now, I am running a Vue app within a phoenix app. I first created a phoenix project and then started a `Vue` app with the name of `assets`.. for running it in the development environment. I have added

```
watchers: [npm: ["run", "build", cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]
```

which each time creates a `build` which is being used in `app.html.eex` from   `priv/static`..

and For deployment, I am using phoenix static build pack.. which in production before deploy creates a build before ahead and then run phoenix app. everything is working fine. but its wrong way due to which..

overall benefits of Vue application is not being availed. e.g code splitting/loading code chunk on-page request only. and many other `webpack` features which we can avail within a Vue app are all not being availed as we just creating the build and putting it in production.

My issue is that. I have seen in may tutorials that run a Vue app with your API as a proxy. and so that the main app will be Vue and Phoenix API will work behind a proxy.

Right now I have this setup to deploy and work in development mode. My question is how I can achieve the opposite to that?

Starting Vue application which will automatically start the phoenix app as well. Also for deploying on Heroku. API will run simply but Vue app will for more functional than just a JS or CSS file static files?

Update: Is it possible to make an umbrella application in which one is Vue and one is phoenix?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an extended comment, but it was getting really big so I moved it to an answer.

To start two or more apps you will need something like foreman (in heroku, I think there's a buildpack with it) or systemd, or even start a nodejs server from your elixir app (not sure this is doable in heroku).

You can also split manually your components through the webpack config used by phoenix, this can be a bit more involved than just serving a single js file. The reason to split it into two separate services needs to be thought of, but this is usually achieved (if I'm not mistaken, it's been a while since I used it in this way) with having different entry points. For webpack to work the best with splitting assets (css&others) you'll need to also write your vue components in a way that webpack can then understand the dependencies (at least this was the case - and there might be some complexities with the webpack chunking and phoenix digest when using dynamic components, etc).

Other option is to, for instance, use an independent nuxt app, which bundles up a VueJS app with everything you need, webpack, server, vuex, a sensible config and "structure" etc. Now you have two distinct applications, running each an http server, you use asyncData & fetch to populate/hidrate your front-end with data from the phoenix app, you can use async components and all that stuff. Then you deploy the front-end (nuxt app) to one heroku instance and the phoenix server on other instance or somewhere else.

At that point your phoenix app is basically an api for the front-end. So the vue app has to be built with that in mind, and now you've got 2 applications to deploy&take care of. It does help in a lot of fronts but it's also more complexity (authorization, cookies, etc), hence why it needs to be weighted if it's worth doing it. The major benefit is that since they're now 2 apps, styling and things related to the front-end can be deployed without needing to re-deploy the back-end.

Depending on the type of front-end you can also deploy the nuxt app as a static website to something like s3/cloudfront or any other cloud storage engine. For instance if you have like, X public pages that are all mostly static content and  everything that is dynamic data is behind a login wall or something, then that is a solution that works fine too.

All 3 ways are valid depending on what you need/reason to do it.